# How to remove the seconds part from a date and time property

Tags: date-time, display-template, managed-property, content-search-web-part, date-format

We have a standard Calendar app in SP2013 with some events that we roll up on a homepage using a content search web part (the Two Lines display template). We show two properties: the title and the start date of the event. The latter one is a managed property mapped to "EventDate". See screenshot.

It shows this property on the homepage as follows: "6-5-2015 07:00:00". How can I remove the seconds part (so the last two :00's) from the time notation? (because it's irrelevant to the user).

Can I change this in the Search Schema or does it require a code change in the display template? If it's code, please be specific and detailed as I'm not a  developer. Your help would be appreciated! :)

By the way: perhaps handy to know: region settings of the site are as follows:

timezone: UTC+01:00 Amsterdam (which is correct)
country: Netherlands
time format: 24 hours
standard language: Dutch

[image]

Comment: Je vraag staat nog steeds als onbeantwoord in de lijsten, mogen we 'm afsluiten?

Comment: yes, mag afgesloten worden.

Comment: Ik zie dat ik nog geen vragen mag sluiten... ik mag alleen vragen sluiten als er een probleem mee is. Je kunt zelf een antwoord markeren...

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a question similar to this before. You can achieve this by doing some changes in a copy of the display template that you are using to modify the date and time output to anything you like.

I'm not going to write it down again but i cover all the steps that you need to do here. The only difference is that i'm working with a different Display Template.

[How-to-modify-time-format-property-mapping](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144228/how-to-modify-time-format-property-mapping/144249#144249)

This site is a big help when creating a custom date output.

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In a ListView you can use the TEXT function in a Calculated Column;

see https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

```
TEXT ([DateTimeField],'dd-mm-yy hh:mm')
```

In a DisplayForm or Search results it is a minor javascript change to the DisplayTemplate

SharePoint adds a `String.format`
you can use/mix all these markers to format a Date value

```
String.format("{0:i}",new Date());  outputs: Wed Oct 07 2015 20:39:54 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
String.format("{0:F}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39:54
String.format("{0:f}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39
String.format("{0:D}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015
String.format("{0:s}",new Date());  outputs: 2015-10-07T20:39:54
String.format("{0:d}",new Date());  outputs: 10/07/2015
String.format("{0:dd}",new Date());  outputs: 07
String.format("{0:ddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wed
String.format("{0:dddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday
String.format("{0:m}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:M}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:MM}",new Date());  outputs: 10
String.format("{0:MMM}",new Date());  outputs: Oct
String.format("{0:MMMM}",new Date());  outputs: October
String.format("{0:Y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:yy}",new Date());  outputs: 15
String.format("{0:yyyy}",new Date());  outputs: 2015
String.format("{0:gg}",new Date());  outputs: A.D.
String.format("{0:T}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39:54
String.format("{0:t}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39
String.format("{0:HH}",new Date());  outputs: 20
String.format("{0:mm}",new Date());  outputs: 39
String.format("{0:ss}",new Date());  outputs: 54
String.format("{0:tt}",new Date());  outputs: AM or PM
```

J1 J5